# What does ‘serial’ do?

Tags: raku

From the [docs](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/serial) that say,

```
Returns the self-reference to the instance itself:
    my $b; # defaults to Any 
    say $b.serial.^name;   # OUTPUT: «Any␤» 
    my $breakfast = 'food';
    $breakfast.serial.say; # OUTPUT: «food␤»
```

I do not have the foggiest what this routine does, please can someone explain?

Comment: We could, but it would help if you also raise this issue in the docs repo.

Comment: done https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/2780

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On `Supply`s, it is an informational method that is supposed to indicate whether there will never be any concurrent `emit` on that Supply.

On `HyperSeq` and `RaceSeq`, it returns a serialized `Seq`, so you could consider it the opposite of the `hyper` and `race` method.

In general, it appears to return itself, which seems to make sense from the `HyperSeq` and `RaceSeq` point of view.

And yes, these should be documented properly, so please create a documentation issue.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

In the doc example it does nothing. That is, if you remove it you get the same results:

```
my $b; # defaults to Any 
say $b.^name;   # OUTPUT: «Any␤» 
my $breakfast = 'food';
$breakfast.say; # OUTPUT: «food␤»
```

More generally, I think you'd best ignore the `serial` method other than to open a doc issue pointing to this SO if you'd like to improve the doc.

## The `serial` method does not appear to be in the official language

[A search of the roast repo for "serial"](https://github.com/perl6/roast/search?q=serial) yields zero matches.

Within Rakudo source code the method name `serial` has been overloaded to have one of three meanings:

- A boolean declaring whether a `Supply` sequence  is always serial. Rakudo source examples: [1](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/45eb1c5f3478aef7c2610fd5cfd9781acb60abd8/src/core/signals.pm6#L58), [2](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/45bbc9465c9d77e26c1584b15ce6500507948d51/src/core/Proc/Async.pm6#L68). This looks to me like an internal method that doesn't need to be documented.
- A coercion of parallel sequence ([hyper](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/5f1a81e0fa9106dfdf9ca596daca83170213c688/src/core/HyperSeq.pm6#L39) or [race](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/5f1a81e0fa9106dfdf9ca596daca83170213c688/src/core/RaceSeq.pm6#L42)) to a serial version of the same sequence. This looks to me like an internal method that doesn't need to be documented.
- A  ["no op"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) that returns its invocant. I suspect it would be best if it were not documented, at least until such time as its raison d'etre is clear; its official status viz-a-viz the spec (roast) is clear; and/or there's an attempt to systematically document which operations have the `is nodal` set on them.

None of the above seems to warrant ordinary users' attention or documentation.

## The `Any` class definition of a `serial` method seems pointless

[The `Any` class `serial` method](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/c45d2b82dafd16d542c29f79433f365672792aa5/src/core/Any.pm6#L66) returns `self`, i.e. when called it is a no op.

I don't currently understand why there is an `Any` class definition.

One possible point for it would be that there are `.serial` calls made by internal code on instances of an unknown and generally unknowable class and there thus needs to be a default definition of `serial` in the `Any` class.

But [a search of the rakudo repo for ".serial"](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?q=%22.serial%22) suggests that calls are only made to supplies or hyper/race seqs.

That said, I note the `is nodal` trait on the `proto serial` declaration in `Any` that immediately precedes the `multi method serial` declaration. Perhaps that is the reason it's in `Any`.

See also [Arbitrary drift of methods to `Mu` and `Any`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1575).

## The documentation you quoted seems pointless

The definition and example seem to reflect someone's sense of humor. I applaud use of humor but in this case I suspect the best improvement would be to just remove the page you linked.